# Is it possible to call a method of all the objects in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

Lets say I have an array of JLabels called catNames, and I want to change the text on all of them (using catNames[i].setText) to "Garfield".

I know it's possible using a loop or doing them all one at a time, but is there a way to do it all in one go?

Thanks!

So sorry, talking about java my bad.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us in which programming language you want to achieve this?

Comment: @pabombs You should always indicate your programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 8, you can use lambdas:

```
    List<TestObject> list = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        list.add(new TestObject(i));
    }
    list.forEach((TestObject element) -> System.out.println(element.toString()));
```